# Flask MySQL connection error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, flask

When I try to send data in Flask to the HTML page for the progress bar, I get an error message:

*cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'*

I know that means there is no connection to the database. If I uncomment `yield "data:" + str(row) + "\n\n"`, there is no errors and database is connected.

```
@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    def generate():
        while 1:
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM log_data WHERE id =( SELECT MAX(id) FROM log_data);")
            mysql.connection.commit()
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()

            for row in records:
                print(row)
                yield "data:" + str(row[1]) + "\n\n"
                time.sleep(0.5)
                break

    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Here is the script in the HTML:

```
var source = new EventSource("/progress");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);

        if(event.data == 100){
            source.close()
        }
    }
```

Why such a thing arises and how it would be possible to send streaming data to the HTML page in Flask?

Comment: Where is `mysql` coming from? That likely matters.

Comment: It is Heroku Add-on ClearDB MySQL. But why is this important? Otherwise, the communication with the database works well.

Comment: It matters because there are several packages for accessing mysql, and without knowing with you're using, and being able to cross-check that documentation, digging in to this question requires too much guess work.